# Unable to insert record using the ExecuteScalar or ExecuteNon-Query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-administration, executenonquery, executescalar

I have a database with a role sa.

When I execute the stored procedure which inserts a record to the table. However, when I run the same stored procedure via the ADO.NET code, the record is not getting inserted successfully. However, I can see that that the stored procedure has been called and runs successfully up to `ExecuteQuery`.

Tried adding a transaction and commit and still no luck.

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
{
    conn.Open();

    using (SqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        command.CommandText = "InsertData";
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", Id);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", Name);                       

        command.ExecuteNonQuery();              
    }   
}
```

Stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertData]
    @Id INT,
    @name VARCHAR(50)
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO Employee (Id, Name) 
    VALUES (@Id, @name)
GO

var ConnectionString = "Data Source=xxxx;Initial Catalog=xxxx;Persist Security Info=True;User Id=xxxx;Password=xxxxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=True";
```

Comment: Show us the code. Both the Store Procedure and the `ExecuteQuery()`

Comment: Do you get an exception? if so, what is it?

Comment: Psychic powers suggest that you are inside a transaction you haven't shared with us, and you need to commit that transaction.

Comment: No exception..works successfully but records not inserted.. :(

Comment: @ChrisNielsen no transactions.. I tried adding a transaction and committing it.. Still no luck

Comment: Check and then double check your connection string. In almost every question like this that I have seen, it turns out that the code was working fine, just not inserting to the database/server that was being checked for the existence of a record.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Code and sproc is available

Comment: @GarethD connection string looks alright to me... checked several times...

Comment: side note: [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: When you say *"I can see that that the sproc has been called*" - how are you checking this? If you haven't already, you could run a trace with SQL Server Profiler to see what commands are being run on the database.

Comment: @GarethD "I can see that that the sproc has been called" = using sql trace

Comment: Put a try catch block in but you said it is not throwing an error

Comment: @Dev on which database? Typically when people have such questions they are either targeting the wrong database (dev vs test) or use a user-instance database that gets replaced every time they restart debugging. What does the connection string look like? Does it have an `AttachDbFileName` keyword?

Comment: @Dev *post* the connection string here, don't say it looks OK. Clearly something isn't OK. It could be a user-instance DB, it could be a LocalDB that gets rebuild by some migration script

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos added connection string

Comment: @Paparazzi I have try catch block as well... Not hitting catch block as there are no errors

Comment: @ChrisNielsen you were right. It was transaction scope in C# code in a different layer.....

Answer (score 2):

Finally resolved after spending a day on it...I was using a legacy code. Someone who is very brilliant has got a transaction open using C# code . and we have these methods where you create a new sql connection string which inserts the data and then since we have not got that transaction complete- It was not inserting a record..

So best way to resolve this is find the word 'transaction' and you may find something like :

```
TransactionOptions options = new TransactionOptions();
options.IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted;
transaction = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew, options);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine, can you try doing this?

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    {
        conn.Open();

        using (SqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            string cmd = string.format("INSERT INTO PaymentDevices (Id, Name) VALUES ({0}, '{1}')",Id,Name);
            command.CommandText = cmd;
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();              
        }   
  }
```

This will help you to identify where your problem is, if it works then the problem is your *SP call* itself, if it does not work the problem is in your *connection string* or a *transaction open*